# Send E-mail periodically to mail addresses stored in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron

I am trying to create a website that needs to send Email every day to the mail addresses stored in mysql. After I googling I found cron concept can be used to do this. I need to know which is the best way to do this. If cron is the best one explain me how can i create the cron file in php. I am using XAMPP in windows.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: XAMPP can't use Cron jobs. You need to set up a Windows Task that runs the php file

Comment: When I'm hosting that website is that possible to perform the windows task on the server..!

Comment: Depends on what you kind of server you are running? Will you be doing it on a Linux server? or Windows?

Comment: you need to host first for enable cron. Because different hosting server had different process to do this.

Answer (score 1):

for windows you may need to try this,

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

or check this one, contains more detail

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is write the php script that preforms the actions you wish, then create a cron job that executes the script. Check out this link https://drupal.org/node/31506, while it pretains to drupal the concepts should apply just fine for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple php file for sending mail with your specific logic. Then you just call that php file via cron job. The process depends on your hosting server. So first decide about hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup something called a CRON job on your server.

If you are using a a hosting service, this can be done in control panel.

If you are using control panel, good explanation here:

http://kb.enoi.se/setting-up-cron-jobs-scheduled-tasks-from-the-control-panel/